# How to solve this differential equation please?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm trying to solve:

$$\frac{dz}{dx}+2xz=2x$$

I have got the integrating factor as $$e^{\int 2x dx}=e^{x^2}$$ and so $$ze^{x^2}=\int {2xe^{x^2}} dx+ C$$

But I don't know how to proceed it's mainly an issue with calculating

$$\int {2xe^{x^2}} dx$$

Any help?

Comment: Hint: sub $u = x^2$. Expanded into an answer below (before it was clear you'd already "got" it). :)

Comment: Got it can't believe I didn't spot that instantly thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a $u$-substitution if you put $u = x^2$. Or, to do it in one step, put $u = e^{x^2}$. Then $du = e^{x^2}*(2x) dx$. So your integral is
$$
u + C = e^{x^2} + C.
$$

Comment: Got it can't believe I didn't spot that instantly thanks!

Comment: @Mike After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $u = x^2$. Then $du = 2xdx$, and the integral is simply $\int e^u du$.

Answer (score 0):

For this differential equation, you don't really need an integrating factor
$$\frac{dz}{dx}+2xz=2x$$
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=2x-2xz$$
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=2x(1-z)$$
$$\frac{1}{1-z}\frac{dz}{dx}=2x$$
$$\frac{1}{1-z}dz=2x\ dx$$
$$\int\frac{1}{1-z}dz=2\int x\ dx$$
Let $u=1-z$, then $-du=dz$. So now we have
$$-\int\frac{1}{u}du=2\int x\ dx$$
$$-\ln u=x^2+C$$
$$-\ln(1-z)=x^2+C$$
$$0= \ln(1-z)+ x^2+C$$
$$e^0= e^{\ln(1-z)+ x^2+C}$$
$$1=(1-z)e^{x^2}e^C $$
$$\frac{1}{e^{x^2}e^C}=1-z $$
$$e^{-x^2}e^C-1=-z $$
$$z=1-e^{-x^2}e^C$$
$$z=1+ke^{-x^2}$$